# Physics.Raycasts Ignores skybox

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hi so I am trying to make a FPS weapon system but when I try to shoot in the sky it ignores the skybox and shoots at the ground [So as you can see I am aiming at the sky in the second picture but the raycast seems to go to the ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRm6Q.png)

My code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ARSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canFire { get; private set; } = true;
    public float wait = .25f;
    public bool isFiring = false;

    public TrailRenderer BulletTrail;
    public ParticleSystem HitEffect;
    public ParticleSystem MuzzleFlash;
    public ParticleSystem MuzzleFlash2;
    public Transform RaycastOrigin;
    public Transform RaycastDestination;

    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit HitInfo;


    void Update()
    {
        

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, HitInfo.point, Color.green, 1f);
            Debug.DrawRay(HitInfo.point, HitInfo.normal, Color.red, 1f);

            StartCoroutine(FireCoroutine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FireCoroutine()
    {
        while (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            StartFiring();

            ray = new Ray(RaycastOrigin.position, RaycastDestination.position - RaycastOrigin.position);
            var tracer = Instantiate(BulletTrail, ray.origin, Quaternion.identity);
            tracer.AddPosition(ray.origin);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out HitInfo))
            {
                HitEffect.transform.position = HitInfo.point;
                HitEffect.transform.forward = HitInfo.normal;
                HitEffect.Emit(1);

                tracer.transform.position = HitInfo.point;
                Destroy(tracer.gameObject, .015f);
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
        }

        StopFiring();
    }

    public void StartFiring()
    {
        isFiring = true;
        MuzzleFlash.Emit(1);
    }

    public void StopFiring()
    {
        isFiring = false;
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the positon of the bullet an watched and researched about it and still nothing.

Comment: Don't store the hit info as a memeber variable. It's going out of date as soon as you don't hit anything, but other area's of your code are treaing it as valid